# GCC-4.2 Failed With Error Code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gcc, ios4

I am receiving the following error out of the blue after trying to build my iPhone Application onto my iPod Touch:

```
Command /Xcode3/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I am also receiving the following warnings which I presume have something to do with this error, maybe a possible cause:

```
ld: warning: in /Users/Max/git/iTopCharts/iTopCharts/Classes/NSAdditions/libNSAdditions_Device.a, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: warning: in /Xcode3/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file


ld: in /Xcode3/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

All help with this is extremely appreciated, as I have spent days making this application.

Comment: The iOS platform doesn't run on i386 hardware. My guess is that your build settings target the iOS platform but the i386 architecture, a combination that doesn't work.

Comment: I am running it for iPhone SImulator, and there seemed to be nothing strange with my build settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by many different problems.

1. Sometimes it gets called, when some file has been deleted, but its reference is still in the Xcode.

OR

1. It might occurs, if you have copy-pasted data from some other project. In some cases, Xcode keeps the reference with it. (If this is the case, then you need to trace that variable, and rename it)

If none of above meets your case, then you need to look at the error in more details. For this,

In xcode, right click the error line and choose "Open These Latest Results as Transcript Text File". This will open the real xcode output log, which should contain a better description of the error then was previously seen.

**EDIT**:Be sure to search 'exit code 1' and the description will be right above the results.
I hope it helps

Comment: I am seeing the last two warnings I posted above. Are they not something to do with Xcode?

Comment: i dont think those warnings are the reason for crash